# pipe buffer contents to shell as pseudo-file

Tags: shell, git, pipe

I'd like to use [wdiff](https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/) to compare the contents of the current buffer to a previous version of the file the buffer is visiting. So, this would be a word-level live diff of the current buffer against a given git commit. The shell version of this would look like this:

```
 wdiff -w "[[delete:" -x "]]" -y "[[insert:"  -z "]]" <(git show "9409c06d816b7c677a4b07b80b76a54d65014257:FILENAME") FILENAME
```

I'd like to replace the second "FILENAME" with something that pipes the contents of hte current buffer to a shell.  Is this possible? The code I am currently stealing from (John Kitchin's scimax package) uses `shell-command-to-string` but that chokes on the buffer string when it contains quotes & special characters.

Comment: Why not just save the buffer contents to a file and pass the file to wdiff?

Comment: I was trying to avoid that step so I could use live updating without adding an I/O bottleneck. But yes, maybe it's the most sensible solution?

Comment: Does `magit-diff-refine-hunk` help? Setting it to `'all` will show word-granularity differences

Comment: Is I/O really going to be a bottleneck here?  I'd suggest testing out the simplest solution first to see if works for you.  If it's too slow, then explore more creative options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can use echo and argument quoting with the subshell method:

```
(shell-command-to-string
 (format "wdiff -w \"[[delete:\" -x \"]]\" -y \"[[insert:\"  -z \"]]\" <(git show efc4752:2018-10-27.org) <(echo \"%s\")"
     (with-current-buffer
         (find-file-noselect "2018-10-27.org")
       (shell-quote-argument
        (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))))
```

This worked for me on a buffer containing quotes and & in it.

Comment: ah, great, thanks John. and now... looks like it'sstill all your code!